# How to Sort Date in LWC Data table in DD.MM.YYYY Format?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, sort

I used below snippet to display Date in DD.MM.YYYY format in lwc datatable

```
{ label: DateofClosure ,
        fieldName: 'ClosedDate',
        sortable: 'true',
        hideDefaultActions: 'true',
        type: "date-local",
        typeAttributes: {
            day:'2-digit',
            month:'2-digit',
            year:'numeric',},
        timezone:"Europe/Berlin"},
```

If the logged in User Locale is German/Germany then the date is displayed in DD.MM.YYYY Format and sorting is also working good in lwc datatable. If the locale is changed then Date format is display based on locale Date format.

I adjusted the code to display in DD.MM.YYYY format for all locale users

```
if (record.CreatedDate) {
                    let dt = new Date( record.CreatedDate );
                    record.CreatedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat( 'de-at' ).format( dt );}
```

then since DD.MM.YYYY is not considered as Date format it is considered as String in cell attributes. Need to sort date in DD.MM.YYYY format in lwc data table, Currently its sorting only on day but not on month, year

Used below sorting logic:-

```
    handleSortCaseData(event) {
            this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
            this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
            this.sortCaseData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
        }

sortCaseData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
        
            parseData.sort((x, y) => {
                x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : '';
                y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
                return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
            });
            this.data = parseData;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your sorting code? LWC datatable itself does not sort anything

Comment: Updated the sorting logic in the question .

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your sorting like so:

```
sortCaseData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        if (fieldName == 'CreatedDate') {
             this.data = parseData.sort((a, b) => {
                                let left = new Date(a.CreatedDate);
                                let right = new Date(b.CreatedDate);
if (direction === 'asc') {
                                return (left < right) ? 1 : ((right < left) ? -1 : 0);
} else {
return (right < left) ? 1 : ((left < right) ? -1 : 0);
}
                            });
      } else {
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
        
            parseData.sort((x, y) => {
                x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : '';
                y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
                return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
            });
            this.data = parseData;
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Tried the above logic earlier and earlier , unfortunately its not working..

Comment: @SFDCLearner ok that means your CreatedDate is not actually Date (i guess after your JSON serialize it is lost), so you need to convert back, try my edited response

Comment: @zaitsaman , Thanks for your response. Yes, your guess is right, CreatedDate is converted to String format once it is converted to DD.MM.YYYY format and I tried above new logic, it still seems to have issue, not sorting properly

Comment: Ok @SFDCLearner I edited again, this code I pulled from my production code base so it definitely works

Comment: I tried above snippet still no luck . I have Created date in string format "CreatedDate":"24.03.2022" , which is not a valid ISO standard date format . I debugged more with console logs noticed that let left = new Date(a.CreatedDate); is not converted to date format and giving error as "Invalid Date".